# How to get values dependent on pairs of id's

Tags: mysql

I have two tables is MYSQL: Users and Relations.

Relations table looks like:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(1,4) 
etc.
```

Users table looks like

```
(1, john)
(2, damian)
(3, amy)
(4, emily)
etc.
```

I want to create a query which will return me pair of names instead pair of id's :

```
(john, damian)
(damian, amy)
(john, emily) 
etc.
```

But i have no idea how.
Thanks for advance for help.

Comment: Show minimal research effort. Did you try `JOIN`?

Comment: Should I join users table "twice" ? I need to get names twice. This is confused for me. SELECT names FROM users JOIN Relations USING(id) will return table with one column of names, i need two columns...

Comment: Exactly join twice to user table (use aliases to refer tables)

Answer (score 2):

```
select (select userName from users where users.id = relations.id1),
(select id from users where users.id = relations.id2) from relations;
```

this model should works

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `left`.name, `right`.name
FROM relations
LEFT JOIN users `left`
ON relations.left_user_id = `left`.id
LEFT JOIN users `right`
ON relations.right_user_id = `right`.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Join first `Users` with `Relations` to find first name and then again with `Users` to find the second name.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8d9a/1)

```
SELECT aa.name, cc.name
FROM Users AS aa
INNER JOIN Relations AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.user_1
INNER JOIN Users AS cc
ON cc.id = bb.user_2
ORDER BY aa.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user1.name, user2.name 
FROM relations
INNER JOIN users AS user1
  ON relations.id1 = user1.id
INNER JOIN users user2
  ON relations.id2 = user2.id
```

Comment: fix your typos **relations** not equal **relation**